# Determining values of cubic function with conditions (calculus)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, cubics

Question: Consider the cubic function $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. Determine the values of
$a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ so that all of the following conditions are met.

a) $′(−1) = 1, ′(0) = −2$,

b) There is a point of inflection at $(1, 0)$

c) The  function $y = f(x)$ intercepts y axis at $(0, 1)$

Find the constants $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

---

This question is really confusing to me as I am still unaware on what the point of inflection is and how to calculate it. Along with that, I don't know how to solve this question. Which formula should I use and what steps do I need to meet the following conditions. Please help. This question is extremely confusing. Thanks!

Comment: i think point of inflection means $f''(x) = 0$ and $f'''(x) \ne 0$

Comment: Unfortunately, there appears to be an inconsistency among the given conditions.  For the other information specified, the intercepts cannot _both_ be at those positions.

Answer (score 2):

find f'$$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d\\\to f'=3ax^2+2bx+c\\\to f''=6ax+2b$$now you have 4 variable and 4 information @ the question
$$f'(-1)=1 \to 3ax^2+2bx+c|_{x=-1}=1\\f'(0)=-2 \to 3ax^2+2bx+c|_{x=0}=-2$$ for inflection point you will have $$f''(x)=0\to 6ax+2b|_{x=1}=0$$ and y-intercept $$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d|_{x=1}=0$$ these all mean
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
3a-2b+c=1\\
0(a)+0(b)+c=-2\\\
6a(1)+2b=0\\
a+b+c+d=0
\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: in the end one should also check $f'''(x) \ne 0$ for that inflection point to make sure it truely is one. Otherwise $f'$ could have a settlepoint there en therefore we dont get an inflection point i guess.

Comment: Hi. How would you find the constants (a, b, c and d) then? If when they add up, they equal to 0? Thanks again!

Comment: @crush3dice I (also) just upvoted your comment, which prompted me to skim the corresponding wikipedia article.  I never suspected that the topic is that complicated and am surprised that the OP would be confronted with this type of complication.  Meta-cheating, I wonder what the **intent** was behind focusing on an inflection point.

Comment: @Panda48490 i guess i would just do it exactly like Khosrotash but in the end check that $f'''(1) \ne 0$. If it isn't then there is no solution, since the solution was unique.

If in general the solution was not unique, the restriction $f'''(1) \ne 0$ would give a subset of the solutionspace that was calculated like Khosrotash did.

Comment: Upon solving the system you arrive at, the coefficients are found to be $$  a = \frac13 \ , \ b = -1 \ , \ c = -2 \ , \ d = \frac83 \ \ . $$  By other approaches, the other posters (**Z Ahmed** and myself) find a slightly different result.  It appears there is an error in the problem in that both intercepts cannot be at the places indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a point of inflexion at $x=1$ then
$$f''(x)=k(x-1) \implies f'(x)=kx^2/2-kx+p \implies f(x)=kx^3/6-kx^2/2+px+q$$
Next, $f'(-1)=1$ gives $1=k/2+k+p=1$, $f'(0)=-2$ gives $p=-2$, we get $k=2$.
Lastly, we use $f(0)=1$, we get $q=1$. So finally t6he cubic is
$$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}-x^2-2x+1.$$

Comment: If you check the value of $ \ f(1) \ $ for your polynomial, you will find that you don't get the $ \ x-$intercept indicated in the conditions (I don't in my answer either).  There appears to be an error among the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

We can also approach this sort of question by using the information provided to solve for coefficients as we go along, so as to avoid having a large system of equations to solve.

We are told outright that the curve for the polynomial has its $ \ y-$intercept at $ \ (0 \ , \ 1) \ $ , so we have $ \ a·0^3 + b·0^2 + c·0 + d \ = \ \mathbf{d \ = \ 1} \ \ . $

The information about one of the points of inflection being at $ \ (  1 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ also gives us one of the $ \ x-$ intercepts of the curve.  As a point of inflection, we have that $$ \ f''(1) \ \  = \ \  6a·1 \ + \ 2b \ \  = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b \ \ = \ \ -3a \ \ . $$

The two values of the slope of the tangent lines to the curves then tell us that
$$ f'(-1) \ \ = \ \ 3a·(-1)^2 \ + \ 2b·(-1) + c \ \ = \ \ 3a·1 \ + \ 2·(-3a)·(-1) \ + \ c \ \ = \ \ 9a \ + \ c \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ ; $$
$$ f'(0) \ \ =  \ \ 3a·0^2 \ + \ 2b·0 \ + \ c \ \ = \ \ \mathbf{c \ \ = \ \ -2} \ \ . $$

We can now solve the first of this pair of equations for $ \ a \ \ : \ \ 9a  +  c \  = \ 9a + (-2) \ = \ 1 $

$ \Rightarrow \ \ 9a \ = \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \mathbf{a \ = \ \frac13} \ \ , $ which leads immediately to $ \ b \ = \ -3a \ \Rightarrow \ \mathbf{b \ = \ -1} \ \ . $  The cubic polynomial is thus $ \ f(x) \ = \ \mathbf{\frac13 x^3 \ - \ x^2 \ - \ 2x \ + \ 1} \ \ . $   This agrees with **Z Ahmed**'s result.

**However,** when we check this against the statement concerning the $ \ x-$ intercept at $ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ \ , $ we find

$$ f(1) \ = \ \frac13 · 1^3 \ - \ 1^2 \ - \ 2·1 \ + \ 1 \ \ \neq \  0 \ \  . $$

So there is an inconsistency in the specification of the conditions for this problem; a graph of the polynomial will confirm this.  My suspicion is that the poser changed one of the details along the way and neglected to check whether anything else was affected, or made a miscalculation in preparing the problem.  (Not that *I've* ever done something like that in making up homework sets or an exam... hrmm...)